# Adding a URL from a field to a PDF get broken when used within an automated email

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

Links to PDFs get broken when used within an automated email

It would seem  the spaces in the between the URL are breaking it up.
I have tried it as a string, description , URL. 
I have tried adding the A href anchor to it but still to no avail.
Any way around this please?

Comment: Hi @mike should you share a screenshot from what you have tried?

Comment: replace the spaces with `%20`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.
In a workflow I copied the field value to another field and then in the email I inserted the latter current field as a hyperlink,

Respect to M.Qassass

Thank you wjervis